# MySQL UNION not returning unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT model,year FROM new_vehicles WHERE make=Ford
UNION
SELECT model,year FROM old_vehicles WHERE make=Ford ORDER BY model
```

I have a while statement in PHP after this to get a list of those models along with year.

The problem is that this prints out duplicate models in the list. If I don't use the year in the query, I get unique list of models. I need the year as I use it in WHILE.

I added distinct after SELECTs above but it didn't change result, likely because UNION returns uniques anyway.

Anyway how to get unique models and include year?

Comment: Will there be the same make/model with different years? if so which year do you want to see? latest? use a 'group by' in your queries and select max(year).

Comment: And if a model/year exists in both tables, do you want it once or twice in the result? (UNION or UNION ALL...) In most cases UNION ALL is the preferred choice, i.e. expected result and faster to compute!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'group by' clause to return one row per model but you then need to decide which year you want to see. I assume the latest.

It may be worthwhile including the 'make' in the query as well. It may make reporting easier.

Untested

```
SELECT make, model, max(year) 
FROM new_vehicles 
WHERE make = 'Ford' 
GROUP_BY make, model
ORDER BY make, model   
UNION 
SELECT model, max(year) 
FROM old_vehicles 
WHERE make = 'Ford' 
GROUP_BY make, model
ORDER BY make, model
```

Comment: Don't you need a GROUP BY in the second SELECT as well?

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your time on this and to all other, but the query return is empty. I will explore an alternative way to return each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT distinct(nv.model),
nv.year as newModelYear, 
ov.year as oldModelYear 
FROM new_vehicles nv, old_vehicles ov 
WHERE 
nv.make = ov.make and 
nv.make= 'Ford'
```